# How to fix the TypeError: predict_proba() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, linear-regression, logistic-regression

For this question, I do not know why it says predict_proba() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'

Can anyone please help me with this?

Here is my code:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('new_customer_info.csv')
df1 = df1.drop(columns = ['person_home_ownership', 'loan_intent', 'loan_grade'])
df1.dropna(inplace=True)
df1['cb_person_default_on_file'] = df1['cb_person_default_on_file'].map({'Y':1 ,'N':0})

X = df1.to_numpy()
from sklearn import linear_model
regression = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regression.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred = LogisticRegression.predict_proba(X)
```

Comment: You were using `LinearRegression` and fit the model on the data. But now you are using `Logistic regression` without fitting the data on. How can you `predict_proba` without fitting the data? should be `regression.predict_proba`

Comment: Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original).

Comment: Thank you for the reminder! I will follow the rules in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using class directly, use object of class `LogisticRegression` which is defined in your code as `regression = linear_model.LogisticRegression()`

Solution:

```
y_pred = regression.predict_proba(X)
```

*Note:
you're also mixing Linear Regression and Logistic Regression. Remember `predict_proba` won't work on regression algos (LinearRegression)*

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help! I used this, however, it appears AttributeError: 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'

Comment: Probability can be calculated on Classification. It will work with Logistic Regression not with Linear Regression